# Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data

Tags: php, timeout, execution-time

I'm trying to run a long-running script that downloads and parses news items for a page. There are about 260+ html pages my script downloads, and parses news items from each page.

It's a long-running script.

If I set the amount of pages it has to parse to something low (meaning it'll take less to execute), the script runs fine:

```
// Since the University blog page has 262 pages, we'll iterate through that.
// Only 21 pages.
for ($i = 2; $i <= 21; $i++) {
    $url = "http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml?AA_SL_Session=34499aef1fc7a296fb666dcc7b9d8d05&scrl=1&scr_scr_Go=" . $i;
    $page = file_get_html($url);
    parse_page_for_news($page, $parsedNews);
}
```

If I increase that page count to 40 or more, the script no longer returns anything at all. On Google Chrome this error message appears:

```
// Since the University blog page has 262 pages, we'll iterate through that.
// 41 pages this time. Longer running time!
for ($i = 2; $i <= 41; $i++) {
    $url = "http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml?AA_SL_Session=34499aef1fc7a296fb666dcc7b9d8d05&scrl=1&scr_scr_Go=" . $i;
    $page = file_get_html($url);
    parse_page_for_news($page, $parsedNews);
}
```

---

> No data received
>
> Unable to load the webpage because the server sent no
>   data.
>
> Here are some suggestions: Reload this webpage later.
>
> Error 324
>   (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without
>   sending any data.

Here are the modifications I made to `php.ini` based on some searching, but still no working fix.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

max_execution_time = 0     ; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_input_time = 60 ; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
memory_limit = -1      ; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
```

Another oddity, when I set the script to run fast (with few iterations), I can actually see the request in the `access_log` file.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2012:15:50:19 -0400] "GET /scrapernoticias/scraper.php HTTP/1.1" 200 509
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2012:15:50:23 -0400] "GET /scrapernoticias/scraper.php HTTP/1.1" 200 509
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Jul/2012:15:58:02 -0400] "GET /scrapernoticias/scraper.php HTTP/1.1" 200 500
```

When I set things to high (long running iterations), I cannot see this new request as if it never even reached the server.

Here is the script in it's entirety:

```
<h1>Scraper Noticias</h1>

<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');
include('rb.php');

// Setup RedBean to work with a database.
R::setup('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=noticias','root','');

set_time_limit(0);

class News {
    var $image;
    var $fechanoticia;
    var $title;
    var $description;
    var $sourceurl;

    function get_image( ) {
        return $this->image;
    }

    function set_image ($new_image) {
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }

    function get_fechanoticia( ) {
        return $this->fechanoticia;
    }

    function set_fechanoticia ($new_fechanoticia) {
        $this->fechanoticia = $new_fechanoticia;
    }

    function get_title( ) {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function set_title ($new_title) {
        $this->title = $new_title;
    }

    function get_description( ) {
        return $this->description;
    }

    function set_description ($new_description) {
        $this->description = $new_description;
    }

    function get_sourceurl( ) {
        return $this->sourceurl;
    }

    function set_sourceurl ($new_sourceurl) {
        $this->sourceurl = $new_sourceurl;
    }
}

// Declare variable to hold all parsed news items.
$parsedNews = array();

// Grab page number 1, and parse that first.
$initialPage = file_get_html('http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml');
parse_page_for_news($initialPage, $parsedNews);

// Since the University blog page has 262 pages, we'll iterate through that.
for ($i = 2; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $url = "http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml?AA_SL_Session=34499aef1fc7a296fb666dcc7b9d8d05&scrl=1&scr_scr_Go=" . $i;
    $page = file_get_html($url);
    parse_page_for_news($page, $parsedNews);
}

echo "<h1>Noticias encontradas:" . count($parsedNews) . "</h1>";
//echo print_r($parsedNews[count($parsedNews) - 1]);

// Save each parsed news to the database.
foreach($parsedNews as &$tmpNews) {
    $noticia = R::dispense('noticia');
    $noticia->imagen = $tmpNews->get_image();
    $noticia->fecha = $tmpNews->get_fechanoticia();
    $noticia->titulo = $tmpNews->get_title();
    $noticia->url = $tmpNews->get_sourceurl();
    $noticia->descripcion = $tmpNews->get_description(); 
    $id = R::store($noticia);  
}

// Disconnect from the database.
R::close();

// Function receives an HTML Dom object, and the library works against that single HTML object.
function parse_page_for_news ($page, &$parsedNews) {

    foreach($page->find('#cont2 p') as $element) {

        $newItem = new News;

        // Parse the news item's thumbnail image.
        foreach ($element->find('img') as $image) {
            $newItem->set_image($image->src);
            //echo $newItem->get_image() . "<br />";
        }

        // Parse the news item's post date.
        foreach ($element->find('span.fechanoticia') as $fecha) {
            $newItem->set_fechanoticia($fecha->innertext);
            //echo $newItem->get_fechanoticia() . "<br />";
        }

        // Parse the news item's title.
        foreach ($element->find('a') as $title) {
            $newItem->set_title($title->innertext);
            //echo $newItem->get_title() . "<br />";
        }

        // Parse the news item's source URL link.
        foreach ($element->find('a') as $sourceurl) {
            $newItem->set_sourceurl("http://www.uvm.cl/" . $sourceurl->href);
        }

        // Parse the news items' description text.
        foreach ($element->find('a') as $link) {
            $link->outertext = '';
        }

        foreach ($element->find('span') as $link) {
            $link->outertext = '';
        }

        foreach ($element->find('img') as $link) {
            $link->outertext = '';
        }

        $newItem->set_description($element->innertext);

        // Add the newly formed NewsItem to the $parsedNews object.
        $parsedNews[] = $newItem;

        // For debugging purposes, it'll print each parsed News Item.
        //print_r($newItem);
        //echo "<br /><br /><br />";

    }
} 

?>
```

Comment: I know you've set `max_execution_time` to 0, but what happens if you call `set_time_limit(0);` at the top of the script?

Comment: @DaveRandom: Just tried your suggestion, and still getting the same results - an empty response from the server.

Comment: An actually empty response (not even any headers) implies the HTTP server is crashing in some way - how are you running PHP, on what web server/OS? Also, does the server error log have anything to say about this?

Comment: Don't know by default on OSX, have a look what the `ErrorLog` directive is set to in httpd.conf

Comment: @DaveRandom: Added the new log information and confirmed a new possible lead on figuring out what the issue is. See edit.

Comment: Sounds like a segfault to me, I wonder if it's one specific page it doesn't like? Try increasing the initial value of `$i` to something greater than 41

Comment: If it is a segfault, you'll see `SIGSEGV` output if you run the script from the command line - which it's generally worth doing, because you may get other useful debugging info as well there, and the CLI SAPI is hardcoded with no time limit

Comment: Also note that what you are looking at there is the access log, not the error log, the error log file is probably in the same location though

Comment: You were right, this is what I find the `error_log` file. `[Fri Jul 27 15:56:52 2012] [notice] child pid 11744 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)` - What does this mean?

Comment: It means that this is a very suitable place to ask this question - [the stack is overflowing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). This can be *extremely* hard to debug in PHP, and the problem lies not within your code but within simplehtmldom or possibly some bad C++ in the version of PHP you're using - although it would be worth you showing your `parse_page_for_news()` function, as it could be a recursive function call or an infinite loop within that causing the problem.

Comment: @DaveRandom: I've added in my very small script in it's entirety. Maybe something jumps out at you as being the culprit. I'm honestly stumped, I'm only using a simple POCO class and two small libraries.

Comment: Nothing leaping out at me, I suspect it will be one specific page that is at fault here, can you add `echo "$i<br />\n"; flush();` at the beginning of the loop and see if it always stops at the same value of `$i`? I would be surprised if it doesn't. It would also be worth adding an `echo "whatever"; flush();` between `file_get_html()` and `parse_page_for_news()` to see whether it is simplehtmldom failing on load or something your function does that causes it (I suspect the former)

Comment: If it is simplehtmldom that's at fault it's likely you could sort the problem out by using PHP's native DOM, unless it's a page that's so large it actually uses *all* the spare memory on you machine, but I find that highly unlikely.

Comment: @DaveRandom: It seems adding that call to flush() made it work... extremely odd. I have no idea why this is working now.

Comment: ...and it actually now runs to the end? That is weird, I couldn't even begin to guess as to why that would actually *fix* it. Have you got output buffering turned on in php.ini?

Comment: I haven't touched anything in `php.ini` besides what's listed at the top. And yes, now it ran until the end with zero issues. :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: No worries. I feel it's an ugly solution though because I have no idea why it fixes it, will you try removing the `flush()` and instead call [`gc_collect_cycles()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) at the end of each iteration of the loop? I'm now wondering if calling `flush()` causes the garbage collector to run, freeing up memory and so preventing the stack from overflowing